# Priority/Cascading datetime without full table scan

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

```
SELECT IF(priority_date, priority_date, created_at) as created_at
FROM table
WHERE IF(priority_date , priority_date , created_at) 
    BETWEEN '2017-10-10 00:00:00' AND '2017-10-10 23:59:59';
```

**What is the best way to execute this query, performance-wise?**

I have a fairly large table that has two datetimes. `created_at` and `priority_date`.

`priority_date` doesn't always exist, but if it does, it should be what is queried upon, else it falls back to `created_at`. `created_at` is always generated upon creation of the row. The above query causes a (nearly) full table scan.

The explain plan for initial query:

```
+------+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table           | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | table           | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 444877 | Using where |
+------+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
```

I should also note that `priority_date` or `created_at` may not necessarily both be within the time frame in question on a single row. So doing something like:

```
WHERE priority_date BETWEEN '2017-10-10 00:00:00' AND '2017-10-10 23:59:59'
OR created_at BETWEEN '2017-10-10 00:00:00' AND '2017-10-10 23:59:59'
```

Could give bad results if `priority_date` was `2017-10-04 23:10:43` and `created_at` was `2017-10-10 01:23:45`

My current rows for said table: `582739`

Count of `WHERE priority_date BETWEEN...` : 3908

Count of `WHERE created_at BETWEEN...`: 3437

Example explain of just one of the columns queried in WHERE BETWEEN:

```
+------+-------------+-----------------+-------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+------+------+-----------------------+
| id   | select_type | table           | type  | possible_keys                    | key                              | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                 |
+------+-------------+-----------------+-------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+------+------+-----------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | table           | range | table_created_at_index           | table_created_at_index           | 5       | NULL | 3436 | Using index condition |
+------+-------------+-----------------+-------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+------+------+-----------------------+
```

Clearly the `IF` is not the most efficient. The columns are indexed and the explains of individual rows are matching to their counts for rows on the explain plan. How can I leverage having a priority/fallback query without the wild performance loss?

**EDIT**

The best I've been able to figure (But WOW, is that verbose and copy/paste-y feeling)

```
SELECT IF(priority_date, priority_date, created_at) as created_at, priority_date
FROM table 
WHERE priority_date BETWEEN '2017-10-10 00:00:00' AND '2017-10-10 23:59:59'
    OR created_at BETWEEN '2017-10-10 00:00:00' AND '2017-10-10 23:59:59'
HAVING ((priority_date AND priority_date BETWEEN '2017-10-10 00:00:00' AND '2017-10-10 23:59:59')
    OR created_at BETWEEN '2017-10-10 00:00:00' AND '2017-10-10 23:59:59');
```

And its explain plan:

```
+------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table           | type        | possible_keys                                                         | key                                                                   | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                                                                                |
+------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | table           | index_merge | table_priority_date_index,table_created_at_index                      | table_priority_date_index,table_created_at_index                      | 6,5     | NULL | 7343 | Using sort_union(table_priority_date_index,table_created_at_index); Using where                      |
+------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: _If "other columns are involved", then none of the answers may apply!_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need a compound index on (priority_date, created_at), then you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT IF(priority_date, priority_date, created_at) as created_at, priority_date
FROM table 
WHERE priority_date BETWEEN '2017-10-10' AND '2017-10-10 23:59:59'
  OR (priority_date IS NULL AND created_at BETWEEN '2017-10-10' AND '2017-10-10 23:59:59');
```

Having priority_date first in the compound index makes a big difference.  No union is required.

Explain results on 400k rows with 2000 results:

```
Extra: Using where; Using index
key: priority_created_compound
rows: 2000
```

Comment: And after adding the compound index, you can remove the individual index on priority_date to save space.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT priority_date as created_at
FROM table
WHERE priority_date BETWEEN '2017-10-10 00:00:00' AND '2017-10-10 23:59:59'

UNION ALL

SELECT created_at
FROM table
WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2017-10-10 00:00:00' AND '2017-10-10 23:59:59'
 AND priority_date IS NULL;
```

You'll need an index starting with `priority_date` for the first half of this query, and an index on `(created_at, priority_date)` for the second half.

The first half will naturally not match any rows where the priority_date  is NULL.

The second half will do the range-condition on created_at, and then among the subset of matching rows, further test that priority_date is NULL. This may be done by index condition pushdown.

Comment: Both of the columns are already indexed, so that won't be too hard to satisfy.. Are you saying that the second unioned query would require a compound index? Also, my example is simplistic, there are other columns involved, so each union would have to list all desired columns.

Comment: The second query would benefit from a compound index, yes. Read about https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-condition-pushdown-optimization.html to understand why.

Answer (score 0):

```
( SELECT  priority_date AS created_at
    FROM  table
    WHERE  priority_date >= '2017-10-10'
      AND  priority_date <  '2017-10-10' + INTERVAL 1 DAY )
UNION  DISTINCT 
( SELECT  created_at
    FROM  table
    WHERE  created_at >= '2017-10-10'
      AND  created_at <  '2017-10-10' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
      AND  priority_date IS NULL )
```

With

```
INDEX(priority_date, created_at)  -- in this order
```

Notes:

- This way to do `BETWEEN` works better for date ranges other than `DATETIME`, plus avoids computing leap days, etc.  (This is no performance difference.)
- For each subquery, the one index is "covering" and optimal.  No ICP should be needed.
- I chose `DISTINCT` on the `UNION` -- Though slower than `ALL`, it may be more to your app's liking.  Switch to `ALL` if there can't be dups, or if dups are OK.